# How to install Plugins install plugins in Datatables?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, plugins, datatables

I'm using DataTables with Codeigniter, but I'm stuck with plugins, I don't know how to install a Datatables plugin. Is a folder? or something like that?

Please, any help will be appreciated.

I search in google, but I didn't find the solution, I'm not an expert developer, I'm a beginner.

Comment: I suggest to read this, it's all explained there https://datatables.net/. Place the corresponding scripts at the end of the *view* file, which uses datatables

Comment: you didn't find anything on google for datatables?